# How shall I implement operator overloading in base class for base class part of derive class object?

Tags: c++

How shall I implement operator overloading in base class for base class part of derive class object?

Please see this sample  code and implement base class part to implement * operator on derive class object

```
class base {
     int x;
public:

};

class der : public base {
    int y;
public:
    const der operator*(const der& rh) {
        der d;
        d.y = y * rh.y;
        return d;
    }

};
```

Comment: @MikeSeymour: To me it seems that the `operator*` implementation only changes a single value, `d`, which is constructed inside the function. It doesn't modify the `rh` argument nor `*this`.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: You're right, I misread it; I just saw that it wasn't `const`, and glossed over the rest. It must be too early in the morning.

Comment: `const der operator*(const der& rh) {...}` should read `der operator*(const der& rh) const {...}`: you do not want the result to be const, but the object you are working on (*this).

Comment: The most useful answer is that you shouldn't. The design is confusing and error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

```
class base {
     int x;
public:
     base & operator *=(const base &rh) {
         x*=rh.x;
         return *this;
     }
     base operator *(const base &rh) {
         base b = *this;
         b*=rh;
         return b;
     }
};

class der : public base {
    int y;
public:
    using base::operator*;
    der & operator*= (const der& rh) {
         base::operator*=(rh);
         y*=rh.y;
         return *this;
    }
    const der operator*(const der& rh) {
        der d = *this;
        d*=rh;
        return d;
    }

};
```

Comment: This approach means that `*` is not commutative; `base() * der()` type checks but `der() * base()` doesn't. Furthermore, doing `base() * der()` may have unexpected results (since the operator will only take the `base`-part of the `der` object - which may or may not be what you want).

Comment: @FrerichRaabe I can't follow your point, with this approach there will be no difference between `base() * der()` and `der()*base()` whatsoever. As for having unexpected results for `base() * der()` I agree in general, but that's a general problem. Whether or not this makes sense is determined by the semantics of your classes, and it's the programmers responsibility to control access (via `public` `private` etc.) to reflect those semantics.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the typos, I didn't have a compiler handy (I'm coerced into using windows right now).

Comment: The difference is that `base() * der()` compiles, but `der() * base()` doesn't, because the overload of `operator*` in the `der` class hides the `operator*` in the base class. I'm surprised this works for you, you need a `using base::operator*;` in `der` to avoid this.

Answer (score -1):

Implement a `base::operator *` as below:

```
class base {
protected:
  int x;
public:
  base operator * (const base &rh) {
    base b;
    b.x = x * rh.x;
    return b;
  }
};
```

And call it as,

```
der operator * (const der& rh) {
  der d;
  Base &b = d;  // <---- assign a temporary reference of 'base'
  b = static_cast<Base&>(*this) * rh; // <---- invoke Base::operator *
  d.y = y * rh.y;
  return d;
}
```

Comment: @SteveJessop, I had already changed my post. Actually, since there was only a single variable `x`, I was tempted to give another solution where directly make the multiplication of `x` in `der`. But then I made the solution more generic. Please check.